# call PHP function in backend with ajax call using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to call a PHP function from Ajax request. This PHP function will take more than 2 to 3 Min. to execute And user may not want to wait for 2 min. So for this I am planing to make ajax call and redirect to another page so that User can take another request. Till I did -

```
new Ajax.Request(reloadurl, { 
 method: 'POST', 
 data: $('edit_form').serialize(),
 parameters: $('edit_form').serialize(true)                 
    onComplete: function(transport) {
        //alert(transport.responseText);
        window.location = backurl;  
    },
    onCreate : function () {    
        alert('dsdsdsds');
        window.location = backurl;                          
    },
    onFailure: function() { 
        alert('Something went wrong...');}
    });
```

But Its not working.. Please help me out- Suggest me the way so that I can call another ajax request simultaneously

Comment: "It's not working"... Tell us more ! Do you get JS errors ? Do you see alerts ?

Comment: If you use the network tab in Firebug/chrome developer tools does it show a new call being made?

Comment: Not getting any Js errors. It's not redirect on onCreate and loading the page till the execution of function. After execution then it redirect on "backurl"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do that is like this:

```
<?php 

exec('/usr/bin/php /Path/to/script.php  {$param1} {$param2} > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &'); 

?>
```

And then in script.php you can get the parameters like this:

```
print_r($argv); //print all parameters
echo $argv[0]; //first parameter
```

This will run the php script as a separate thread and not require the user to wait for the output.

I tend to update a file or db to keep track of how the running of the script is going.

Comment: Ya! I know it but I dont want to call exec function or the Cron Job. Because Its a server settings and client don't want to do that.. Is there is another way to do that using Ajax?

Comment: Then the code you have above will wait for the script to execute, that's when the header data will be sent back to your JS.

Comment: Ok. Could you please tell me more on exce function. I mean, I called process() function present in process.php file. I submitted all data to process.php file via POST method to Process() function. So where does I write the exec call? Please help me....

Comment: In process.php you would run exec(... In script.php (or whatever you call it) you would put whatever is in process.php now

Answer (score 0):

Your approach could work, but if you use sessions, you should close manually with [`session_write_close()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) as soon as you won't write to it any more.

> ... session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time